# Hovering over a container div shows hidden div. When cursor is put over hidden div, behavior of container div changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using [this plugin](https://github.com/karlhorky/gray) for cross-browser compatible grayscale images. Basically, the image is originally in grayscale mode with a low opacity. When the user hovers over the image, the grayscale fades to color, the opacity returns to 1, and a previously hidden div slides up from the bottom.

All of this works fine, however, here is the problem: while the user is hovering over the image, if the cursor is moved to the previously hidden div (`.post-info`), the image returns back to grayscale. I would like to keep it in color if possible. Also, if there is a more elegant, cross-browser, mobile-friendly way to achieve this, please feel free to share. I'm always trying to learn how to code more elegantly.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zg0jf2fb/

HTML

```
<article>
    <div class="post-info" style="display: none;">
        <h1 class="entry-title"><a href="/" rel="bookmark">Test</a></h1>
    </div>
    <img width="375" height="375" src="http://i.imgur.com/5Boucbt.jpg" class="grayscale grayscale-fade wp-post-image">
</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
    float: left;
    opacity: .3;
    position: relative;
    width: 375px;
    transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-in-out;
}
article:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
}
article .post-info {
    background: #000;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

/* Grayscale CSS */
.grayscale {
    /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'><filter id='grayscale'><feColorMatrix type='matrix' values='0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0'/></filter></svg>#grayscale");

    /* IE 6-9 */
    filter: gray;

    /*
    Chrome 19+,
    Safari 6+,
    Safari 6+ iOS,
    Opera 15+
    */
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
}

.grayscale.grayscale-fade {
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-filter .2s;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-off,
.grayscale.grayscale-fade:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-replaced {
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: none;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-replaced > svg {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease;
    transition: opacity .2s ease;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-replaced.grayscale-off > svg,
.grayscale.grayscale-replaced.grayscale-fade:hover > svg {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

JS

```
// Hover titles
$('article').hover( function() {
    $(this).find('.post-info').stop().slideDown(100);
    }, function() {
    $(this).find('.post-info').stop().slideUp(100);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is with these two styles:

```
.grayscale.grayscale-off,
.grayscale.grayscale-fade:hover {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-replaced.grayscale-off > svg,
.grayscale.grayscale-replaced.grayscale-fade:hover > svg {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

When you move your cursor to the `div` you are no longer hovering the `img` itself and so it returns to grayscale. In order to keep the coloration when you move the cursor onto the `div` you need to keep the filters off while hovering the `article`, not just the `img`, like so:

```
.grayscale.grayscale-off,
article:hover .grayscale.grayscale-fade {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: none;
}

.grayscale.grayscale-replaced.grayscale-off > svg,
article:hover .grayscale.grayscale-replaced.grayscale-fade > svg {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lhbfsay7/